# Missing DB table for django-background-tasks

Tags: python, django

I'd like to regularly run a backend task in my Django app and found django-background-tasks (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-background-tasks).

Following the page, I

- pip installed the package
- added it to INSTALLED_APPS
- created a test method annotated with @background(schedule=5)

However, once I call the method, I get "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: background_task"

Running `python manage.py migrate` only tells me "No migrations to apply" (the DB has tables for other registered Django apps).

Is the django-background-tasks package incomplete?
How do I create the DB objects for it?

Comment: Did you try `makemigrations`?

Comment: Yes, makemigrations also says "No changes detected"

Comment: Did you try `python manage.py makemigrations background_task`, if yes please post your django, django-background-tasks versions

Comment: That was the trick, "makemigrations background_task". Thanks Ravi and @MosesKoledoye !

Answer (score 6):

As Moses and Ravi suggested, `python manage.py makemigrations background_task` needs to be ran first so that `python manage.py migrate` can create the table.

Comment: This issue should be fixed in the meantime.

Comment: I'm using Django 2.2, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I just get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: background_task`